# Правильная архитектура CMS, без static методов, с глобальным хранилищем и инициализатором Классов.

Tags: php, cms, mvc

Прошу помочь советом и ткнуть носом. Встал в ступор на текущей стадии разработки.

**Краткая логика работы CMS:**
При обращении к сайту, в bootstrap.php происходит include всех необходимых файлов - базовый класс модели, контроллера, smarty(в качестве вьювера), и библиотек(об этом ниже). Далее bootstrap.php запускает маршрутизатор, который разбирает url и соответственно уже создаёт экземпляр класса необходимого контроллера, который работает с моделью и видом. С этим проблем и вопросов не возникает.

**Вопрос возник вот тут**. Как я говорил, у меня есть библиотеки(lib), по сути это простые файлы с классом. Например класс работы с БД - /lib/db.class.php, либо класс работы с сессиями - /lib/session.class.php, есть класс авторизации и регистрации, работы с датой и т.д. К сожалению, я не знаю как эти классы должны правильно называться, поэтому называю их библиотеки и храню в /lib/.

Беда в том, что все классы используют статические методы, и я обращаюсь к ним напрямую как DB::db_select(), DB::db_update, Session::check(), Session::expired($login). Для работы с БД я понимаю, что могу использовать Singleton, но не считаю это выходом.

У меня в голове есть идея, что я должен создать какое-то глобальное хранилище классов, ещё во время выполнения bootstrap.php. И по мере обращения к какому-то классу из любой части приложения, происходит проверка на существование данного экземпляра класса, и при необходимости такой экземпляр создаётся.

И уже в приложении, я мог бы без проблем использовать конструкции типа App::Session->Check(), и в классе App, происходила бы проверка, существует ли экземпляр класса Session, если нет, то создавала бы.

Натолкните как правильно всё-же делать.

Comment: Мне кажется, что вы сами пытаетесь переизобрести известные паттерны **[Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).** См. также http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/dependency-injection-in-php/

Answer (score 1):

Используйте паттерн "Фабрика" вместе с "[Singleton](http://lifeexample.ru/php-primeryi-skriptov/php-singleton-singlton.html)". Singleton позволяет гибко работать с памятью: контролировать утечки, очищать.

```
class App
{ 
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Возвращает instance(ссылку) на объект, если объект был создан ранее, в
     * противном случае инициализирует новый объект
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public static function getInstance() {
        if (self::$instance === null){       
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    /**
     * Фабрика
     *
     * @return object
     */ 
    public static function factory($class_name)
    {   
        if (class_exists($class_name)) {
            self::getInstance();
            if (empty(self::$instance->$class_name)) {
                self::$instance->$class_name = $class_name::getInstance();
            }

            return self::$instance->$class_name;                    
        }

        /* Exception */

    }

    public static function clear() 
    {
        self::$instance = null;
    }   
}

class Foo
{
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct() {}

    /**
     * Возвращает instance(ссылку) на объект, если объект был создан ранее, в
     * противном случае инициализирует новый объект
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public static function getInstance() 
    {
        if (self::$instance === null){       
            self::$instance = new self;
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function get() 
    {
        return 'Hello, World!';
    }

    /**
     * Защищаем от создания через клонирование
     *
     * @return Singleton
     */
    private function __clone() { /* ... */ }

    /**
     * Защищаем от создания через unserialize
     *
     * @return Singleton
     */
    private function __wakeup() { /* ... */ }   
}

App::factory('foo')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Правильно делать вот так: [Dependency Injection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/index.html) :) ну и разумеется можно нарыть русские документации по контейнеру сервисов, но русские доки по симфони отстают от текущих веток, но вроде как за год ничего особо не поменялось в компоненте `dependency injection`.